# Pass data from FlexCard to LWC extending OmniscriptBaseMixin

Tags: lightning-web-components, api, omnistudio

I have a FlexCard. The datasource is the following

```
{ "user": 
  { "userId": "asd134224zdf"}
}
```

There is a custom LWC embedded inside. I am passing the following attribute
`attribute = userid | value = {user.userId}`

My LWC essentially does the following (It does other things, but they are not relevant to my problem):

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
import { OmniscriptBaseMixin } from 'omnistudio/omniscriptBaseMixin'
export default class DeviceRosterLWC extends OmniscriptBaseMixin(LightningElement){
  @api userid;
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('userId: ' + this.userid);
    console.log('userId stringify: ' + JSON.stringify(this.userid));
  }

}
```

Both console logs say

`userId: undefined`

`userId stringify: undefined`

I've tried passing the whole `user` node, but still it comes out undefined. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you have set the `Result JSON Path` as `["user"]`, you can directly access the userId as below.

*Flex Card Setup*

[image]

*LWC JS*

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';
import { FlexCardMixin } from "omnistudio/flexCardMixin";
export default class FlexTestComponent extends FlexCardMixin(LightningElement){
    @api USERID;
}
```

*LWC HTML*

```
<template>
    USER ID - {USERID}
</template>
```

*LWC Added to the Flex Card*

[image]

*LWC Output inside FlexCard*

[image]

Comment: Hi Saroj, I've tried this and USERID still came out as undefined Also, if the LWC has USERID in all caps, then wouldn't we reference it in the FlexCard as u-s-e-r-i-d, as is LWC standard for attributes? 

I changed my class to extend "flexCardMixin" rather than "omniscriptBaseMixin", but that didn't help either.

Comment: `FlexCardMixin` tag I was searching for like hours, when I came across this post. Really helpful. Wondering why is this not part of documentation anywhere.